# Как найти прямоугольник, являющегося пересечением двух других?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, геометрия

Не могу понять, как реализовать метод, касающийся выделенного текста.

> Составить описание класса прямоугольников со сторонами, параллельными
>   осям координат. Предусмотреть возможность перемещения прямоугольников
>   на плоскости, изменение размеров, построение наименьшего
>   прямоугольника, содержащего два заданных прямоугольника, **и
>   прямоугольника, являющегося общей частью (пересечением) двух
>   прямоугольников.** Программа должна содержать меню, позволяющее
>   осуществлять проверку всех методов.

Comment: В качестве иллюстрации, возможно вам поможет: https://codechef_shared.s3.amazonaws.com/download/Rectangle%20Intersection.png

Comment: спасибо, разбираемся

Comment: https://silentmatt.com/rectangle-intersection/ очень помогла вот эта штука, всем ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, задачка не в пару строчек. Сделал программу, проверил, работает как надо:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// просто две координаты
struct vec {
    int x, y;
};

class box {
    // левая нижняя и правая верхняя точки
    vec pos1, pos2;

public:
    // ширина и высота, чтобы вторая точка
    //     была не ниже и не выше первой
    box (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        pos1.x = x;
        pos1.y = y;
        pos2.x = x + w;
        pos2.y = y + h;
    }

    box () {
        // в случае, если не пересекаются, будут нули
        pos1.x = pos1.y = 0;
        pos2.x = pos2.y = 0;
    }

    // поиск пересечения
    box cross (box &another) {
        box result;
        // ящик, потенциально ниже и левее второго
        box *low = this;
        // ящик, потенциально выше и правее первого
        box *high = &another;
        if (another.pos1.x < pos1.x) {
            low = &another;
            high = this;
        }
        // проверки, что ящики пересекаются
        if (high->pos1.x < low->pos2.x) {
            if (low->pos1.y <= high->pos1.y) {
                if (high->pos1.y < low->pos2.y) {
                    // вычисление регулирующих значений
                    result.pos1.x = max(low->pos1.x, high->pos1.x);
                    result.pos1.y = max(low->pos1.y, high->pos1.y);
                    result.pos2.x = min(low->pos2.x, high->pos2.x);
                    result.pos2.y = min(low->pos2.y, high->pos2.y);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // вывод крайних точек ящика
    void print () {
        cout << "x1: " << pos1.x << " y1: " << pos1.y << " x2: " << pos2.x << " y2: " << pos2.y << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    // проверка
    box a(0, 5, 10, 10), b (-5, 0, 10, 50);
    cout << "A: ";
    a.print();
    cout << "B: ";
    b.print();
    box c = a.cross(b);
    cout << "C: ";
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат этого кода таков:

```
A: x1: 0 y1: 5 x2: 10 y2: 15
B: x1: -5 y1: 0 x2: 5 y2: 50
C: x1: 0 y1: 5 x2: 5 y2: 15
```

Comment: @KromStern несколько быстрых проверок прошли успешно. В целом, у меня алгоритм должен быть универсален, ошибки могут быть в пограничных значениях. Хотя заданием и не определено, что должно быть в случае простого касания прямоугольниками.

Comment: @KromStern благодарствую :) Однако считаю, что комментариев мало. Надо это исправить. Кажется, университет хорошо постарался над прививанием этой привычки.

Comment: Нет, конечно, для учебного варианта сойдет, но в целом получилось - "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"

Answer (score 2):

Берете координаты (рассмотрим по x, по y аналогично) -

x1_1, x1_2 - координаты левой и правой стороны первого прямоугольника

x2_1, x2_2 - координаты левой и правой стороны второго прямоугольника

И сравниваем  `max(x1_1,x2_1)` и `min(x1_2,x2_2)`. Если первая величина превосходит вторую - прямоугольники не пересекаются (ну, понятно, надо еще и по y проверять). Если нет - то это и есть координаты по x пересечения.

"По-моему, так" (с) Пух

**Update** Вот как 25 лет назад с этим справлялись в Turbo Vision :)

```
inline void TRect::intersect( const TRect& r )
{
    a.x = max( a.x, r.a.x );
    a.y = max( a.y, r.a.y );
    b.x = min( b.x, r.b.x );
    b.y = min( b.y, r.b.y );
}

inline void TRect::Union( const TRect& r )
{
    a.x = min( a.x, r.a.x );
    a.y = min( a.y, r.a.y );
    b.x = max( b.x, r.b.x );
    b.y = max( b.y, r.b.y );
}

inline Boolean TRect::contains( const TPoint& p ) const
{
    return Boolean(
        p.x >= a.x && p.x < b.x && p.y >= a.y && p.y < b.y
        );
}
```

Comment: @KromStern Перечитал. Я его воспринимал и воспринимаю, особенно с учетом выделения, как: "Предусмотреть 1. возможность перемещения прямоугольников на плоскости, 1. изменение размеров, 3. построение наименьшего прямоугольника, содержащего два заданных прямоугольника, и 4. прямоугольника, являющегося общей частью (пересечением) двух прямоугольников". Если это не так - пишите понятнее...

Comment: @KromStern О "пишите понятнее" - понятно :), не к вам, а к автору...

Comment: @KromStern Ну, когда меня одновременно одолевают педагогический запал (не давать готовое решение) и лень (писать многословно) - я отвечаю вот такими намеками :)  Я чуть исправил ответ, посмотрите...

Answer (score 0):

сдается что должно быть так (координаты растут слева направо и сверху вниз):

```
  c.lt.y=max(a.lt.y,b.lt.y);

  c.lt.x=max(a.lt.x,b.lt.x);

  c.rb.y=min(a.rb.y,b.rb.y);

  c.rb.x=min(a.rb.x,b.rb.x);
```

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так (из гугла, но на бумаге верно):

```
struct point
{
    int x,y;
}
struct rectangle
{
    point lt; //left top
    point rb; //right bottom
}

..... ввод координат ...

if(a.rb.y>b.lt.y || a.lt.y<b.rb.y || a.lt.x>b.rb.x || a.rb.x<b.lt.x)
{
  cout<<"Прямоугольники не пересекаются"<<endl;
}
else
{
  c.lt.y=min(a.lt.y,b.lt.y);
  c.lt.x=max(a.lt.x,b.lt.x);
  c.rb.y=max(a.rb.y,b.rb.y);
  c.rb.x=min(a.rb.x,b.rb.x);
}
```

a и b - исходные прямоугольники, c - пересечение.